# override not allowed outside a class definition

Tags: c++, c++17

I created an abstract class and a concrete subclass:

```
//bca.h
#include <string>
class bca {
public:
    virtual std::string get_virtual_year() const = 0;
};
```

```
//bca_interface.h
#include "bca.h"
class bca_interface : public bca {
public:
    std::string get_virtual_year() const override;
};
```

```
//bca_interface.cpp
#include "bca_interface.h"
std::string bca::get_virtual_year() const override {
    return "";
}
```

When I compile `bca_interface.cpp` with g++, I get:

```
 error: virt-specifiers in ‘get_virtual_year’ not allowed outside a class definition
 std::string bca::get_virtual_year() const override {
```

Comment: `override` keyword can only be used when you override virtual methods.

Comment: Only classes can have virtual functions.

Comment: Please add [mcve]. As of now, this problem can be everywhere. Include both classes declarations.

Comment: I've updated it, is this what you meant?

Comment: remove `override` from cpp

Comment: what's the reasoning for removing it? I'm reading A Tour of C++ and it uses it the same way?

Comment: @user1406186 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override "The identifier override, if used, appears immediately after the **declarator** in the syntax of a member function declaration or a member function definition **inside a class definition**." (emphasis mine)

Comment: You want to define `get_virtual_year()` method from **`bca_interface`**, not from `bca`. BTW, this naming is confusing. Interface is usually used as name for the class with pure virtual methods.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, it *could* have been intentional to implement `bca::get_virtual_year` (but the `override` suggests not).  Don't forget that pure virtual methods are allowed to have definitions in C++, unlike certain other languages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error says it all:

```
error: virt-specifiers in ‘get_virtual_year’ not allowed outside a class definition
```

You cannot put a *virt-specifier* (`override` and `final`) outside of a class definition. You only put that specifier on the function declaration within the class definition. The same is true for, e.g., `explicit`, `static`, `virtual`, ...

Where you have it in the header is correct. In your source, just remove it.

Answer (score 9):

The `override` keyword, is only used in the *declaration* of the member (in the class definition, as the error message says).  That's where it's relevant.

The definition doesn't care whether it's an overriding implementation or not, just that it has the same signature (including `const`).

```
//bca_interface.h
class bca_interface : public bca {
public:
private:
    std::string get_virtual_year() const override;
    //                                   ^^^^^^^^ correct
};
```

```
//bca_interface.cpp
std::string bca_interface::get_virtual_year() const {
    //                                  ^^^ not required (or allowed) here
    return "";
}
```

Of course, if your declaration is also the definition, then `override` is welcome.

Comment: You can put default arguments in the definition.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that's just a warning rather than an error (I usually use `-Werror`).  Your example of `explicit` is better.

Comment: @TobySpeight It shouldn't even be a warning as far as I'm aware. Just don't put default args in more than one declaration (including the defining declaration)